# Periodic thread creation in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I want to achieve the following: "Main thread has to create a child thread at every 3 minutes. Child thread should run independently and main thread has to continue its normal execution and once the child thread is finished, it should exit." 
This is what I have done so far:

```
void thread_timer(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval) {
    std::thread([func, interval]()
    { 
       while (true)
      { 
         auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
         func();
         std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
      }
    }).detach();
}

void foo()
{
   std::cout<<"Doing something...";
}

main_thread_func()
{
   // Doing some task
   while(1) { 
      thread_timer(foo, 180000); // Should be executed every 3mins
      // do some task
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a problem to solve. What have you tried to solve it, and where did you encounter problems?

Comment: where do you have a problem ? about the threads or the timer(/sleep) ? You are not a new member, you should know how to ask a question ;-)

Comment: What you have there doesn't really seem to solve what the problem wants. Instead of the main thread starting a thread every 3 minutes, you have a single child thread executing one function every three minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just speaking about the period doing

> ```
>   while (true)
>  { 
>     auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
>     func();
>     std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
>  }
> ```

you do not execute *func* each 3 minutes but each 3 mins + func-execution-time

Using a similar way can be

```
auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

while (true)
{
   x += std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
   func();
   std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
}
```

if you are sure the execution time of *func* is less of 3 mins else you have to choose between to loose period(s) or to update *x* with the current time

Now your *func* has to create a new thread, but you also have to manage the end of the threads execution except if you detach them